# Branch.io can't use custom fallback_url with long links

Tags: javascript, react-native, branch.io

I successfully implemented Branch.io with my React Native app. Now I'm facing an issue where I can't redirect web users to the right url.

When a user wants to reset his password on my app, he give his email address and I'm sending him the following link :

`https://my-project.app.link/token=12345&$fallback_url=https%3A%2F%2Fmyapp.com%2Freset_password%2F12345`

So that if the user is checking the reset email right from his phone, he can reset the password directly in the app. Otherwise if he's using another device I want him to be redirected to my web password reset form. But for an unknown reason the link never redirects to the $fallback_url but always to the default fallback I've put in my branch.io dashboard. Which is just my website's homepage.

I've tried with the url from the docs : `https://example.app.link/fzmLEhobLD?foo=bar&baz=456&$fallback_url=https%3A%2F%2Fbranch.io%2F` and it's working perfectly even when I change the fallback_url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned you're using a link with a similar format as: https://my-project.app.link/token=12345&$fallback_url=https%3A%2F%2Fmyapp.com%2Freset_password%2F12345

If you dont have an alias after my-project.app.link/XXXXX you will need to add a '?' after the first /. Ex. https://my-project.app.link/?token=12345.........

If you do have an alias, make sure to have a '?' after the alias. Ex. https://my-project.app.link/alias?token=12345.....

If you have further problems, please right into integrations@branch.io with your issue, an example link you are using, and your Branch App ID found in the Account Settings of your Branch Dashboard.

Thanks.